# OpenCV Camera Error

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I want to use my built-in camera on my laptop to capturing video, but it give an error.

Actually I have a project that have to make a program to detecting shape, I already done until the program can detect the shape from a jpeg, but when I edited the code to detecting from a camera, it's come error.

And I use the simple code to run the camera (found on google), and it gives the same exact error when I use my main project program.

The error (I kept click continue) :

```
[1] OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn ==4) in cv::cvtColor, ...

[2] OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width)0 && size.height)0) in cv::imshow,...

[3] OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field0 (.....) in cvGetMat,...
```

I don't know how to deal with the last error, I think the first and second error because my camera haven't ready yet.CMIIW

I use this code to open the camera :

```
VideoCapture cap(0);  //open the default camera
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);     
if (!cap.isOpened())  //check if we succeeded       
return -1;
```

and my camera LED light is on and the "edges" windows that should show the result, but it's just blank.

Hope you can help me.

EDITED : I solved my prob by using :

```
try
        {
            imshow("webcam", frame);
        }
        catch (Exception& e)
        {
            const char* err_msg = e.what();
            std::cout << "exception caught: imshow:\n" << err_msg << std::endl;
        }
```

The [2] error still show up, but after that my cam was work.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, using OpenCV v2.4.10:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);            // Open the default camera
if (!cap.isOpened())            // Check if we succeeded
    return;

string szWebcam = "Webcam - ESC to exit";
namedWindow(szWebcam, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
char cKey = '0';
Mat imgFrame;
for (;;)
{
    cap >> imgFrame;            // Get a new frame from camera
    imshow(szWebcam, imgFrame);     // Show image
    cKey = cvWaitKey(30);
    if (cKey == 27)                 // Is ESC, exit
        break;
}
```

Note that the cap.Set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, xxx) command depends on the capabilities of your camera. For example, on my laptop, the camera can deliver 640x480 (default) or 1280x720 frames. Calling this:

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
```

Makes my camera deliver 1280x720 frames. Curiously, I note that using anything from 640 to 1080 results in frames of 640x480; using anything from 1081 or larger, results in frames of 1280x720. No errors in using numbers not equal to 640 or 1280, though. You should check the specification of your camera. You can also call capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) to get the width of the default frame size.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 with OpenCV v2.4.10. And I have tried your code, It's still give the error [2] and [3], but no [1]. I have used the  cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), but still the same. I don't know, the [2] OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width)0 && size.height)0) in cv::imshow,... It should be because there an error with the width and height right ? My camera led is on and the 'webcam' windows show up but just blank.